# OpenGl es 2.0 android save resources dont change texture

Tags: android, optimization, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently using opengl es 2.0 for my android game and I am trying to optimize it a little. Since the background has about three different images which are already in the opengl texture buffer, I thought it would be possible to leave the first texture drawn active, then draw all the other shapes and then change to the next texture but only three are drawn and the rest is all black. Here is the code:

```
public void drawWithoutTextureChange(float m[]){
    int mPositionHandle =
            GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicsTool.sp_Image,"vPosition");


    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);


    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3,GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);

    int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicsTool.sp_Image,
            "a_texCoord" );

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            0, uvBuffer);

    int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicsTool.sp_Image,
            "uMVPMatrix");

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, m, 0);

    // This normally loads the texture but I disabled it to save resources
    //int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicsTool.sp_Image,
    //       "s_texture" );
    //GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, texture);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < plates.size(); i++) {
            if (!currentTextures.contains(plates.get(i).getTexture()))
                currentTextures.add(plates.get(i).getTexture());

            }
            for(int i = 0; i < currentTextures.size(); i++) {
                //Log.d("Textures ", String.valueOf(currentTextures.get(i)));
                boolean first = true;
                for (int k = 0; k < plates.size(); k++) {
                    if(first == true) {
                        System.out.println("Textures");
                        plates.get(i).draw(m);
                        first =false;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Textures without change");
                        plates.get(i).drawWithoutTextureChange(m);
                    }
                }
            }
```

too load the shapes with the same texture in the right order

I dont really know a lot about opengl, so it would be great if someone could fix this.
Thanks
chopStick